# Passwallet in android

Tags: android, passbook

In my application I want to show pkpass file,so I am using "Passwallet" app for that.When the file gets download,it will open in passwallet app installed in the device.It will show the informations like coupon title,image,qr code and business name.But I want some other informations like coupon code and expiry date.Is it possible to display that also?If yes please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

PassWallet follows the same rendering rules as Passbook, so to show extra information you would need to add in additional fields.

Doc is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/PassKit_Bundle.pdf

- The coupon code could be displayed as the altText of the barcode.
- The expiry date as a primaryFields or secondaryFields
- etc.